# Investigating Segmentation Faults and Debugging Tools

Tags: bash, c++11, segmentation-fault, gdb, gnu-make

After compiling a C++ program with make and gcc I experienced a segmentation fault while running. The program just exited without any error message.

Even though I didn't compile the program in debug mode, by running it with gdb I actually got an error message to see where the segfault happened.

What I would like to know is:

- Why did gdb display the line causing the error, but the regular bash did not?
- How can the gdb display the line when the program was not compiled in debug mode?
- In the past I always re-compiled in debug mode (to attatch the symbolic table to the binaries) and investigted the backtrace of the core dump with ddd. Is this the proper way to fix segmentation faults, or what is the common way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did gdb display the line causing the error, but the regular bash did not?

Because gdb is built to do that.  Trapping the segfault and reporting about it to you is part of its job, to help you debug.  For example, you can then obtain a backtrace, examine the various stack frames, etc. to determine the nature and perhaps the cause of the error.  Bash is not built to do that, and no such behavior is provided for free.

> How can the gdb display the line when the program was not compiled in debug mode?

Clearly some kind of debugging information is inserted into the binary by default, even when you do not ask for it.  Enough, at least, to provide line numbers for code.  If you're using GCC, then that might correspond to `-g1`, whereas `-g` is equivalent to `-g2`.  If you're curious, you could compile with `-g0` to see whether that eliminates the line number information.

> In the past I always re-compiled in debug mode (to attatch the symbolic table to the binaries) and investigted the backtrace of the core dump with ddd. Is this the proper way to fix segmentation faults, or what is the common way to do it?

There's no "proper" here beyond "whatever works".

I do find that its easier to debug programs compiled with optimization disabled, and of course debug information is most helpful -- all provided that you can reproduce the error with such a binary.  I also tend to engage valgrind whenever a program I'm working on segfaults.  That, too, is more informative when debug information is available, and if there is a memory problem (which a segfault almost invariably indicates) then valgrind will likely identify it even if the debug version of the program doesn't crash.  As for ddd, that's just one of several UI choices, including supported tools' native ones.  Use what works for you in that regard.

Oh, and in decades of programming, I've never yet had to resort to analyzing a core dump.  My time may come eventually, of course, but I'm content to defer it.